# Bochner integral on function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, bochner-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $B$ be a Banach space. A Bochner-measurable function $f: X \rightarrow B$ is Bochner integrable if and only if
$$
\int_{X}\|f(x)\|_{B} d \mu(x)<\infty
$$
In that case
$$
\int_{X} f(x) d \mu(x)
$$
is well defined and belongs to $B$. What if $B$ is some space of functions such as $B = \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ the space of bounded linear operators from $E$ to $F$ where $E$ and $F$ are two normed vector spaces and $F$ is complete so that $B$ is a Banach space. Is it always true that, for $e \in E$

$$
\left[\int_{X} f(x) d \mu(x)\right](e) = \int_{X} f(x)(e) d \mu(x). ?
$$
I could not find a reference book explaining that property. I am particularly interested in the setting where $B$ is a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert space.

Comment: My guess is this is true (BTW I think the notation that's typically used is "operator valued function" for $f$). My first idea would be to use the definition of $f$ being B-measurable as the limit of "simple" functions, for which the identity should be easier to prove, then pass to the limit.

Comment: It is certainly true if the evaluation$T \mapsto T(e)$ is continuous on the Banach space $B$ that you are considering. For instance in the case of bounded operators, this is satisfied. The claim then follows since it is known that bounded linear operators commute with the Buchner integral. If you don't have this continuity (e.g., on $L^p$ spaces), the question becomes more subtle.